# Sniping in emacs without using the evil mode

Tags: emacs

I like the sniping mode, that I used in doom emacs with the evil mode.  Is there a way, that I could use something like this in normal emacs?

https://github.com/hlissner/evil-snipe

evil snipe works like this: after pressing a certain shortcut, at each  line a letter will appear and you can press the letter and jump to the location.

Comment: Specify what "sniping" mode in Doom Emacs + Evil mode does. IOW, **specify** the behavior you're looking for. (And maybe it's "snipping", not "sniping"?).

Comment: @Drew is this better?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/abo-abo/avy

Comment: Please describe what you want specifically. *"something like this"*, with a link to the "this" isn't specific. *"jump to a screen location via shortcut"* is too vague. What do you mean by "shortcut": a key binding? a link? Emacs has *many* "shortcut" ways to jump to different places, including different screen locations.

Comment: @Drew i tried again, could you check again please.

Comment: Better. We'll see what answers you get. (Sounds a bit like what Avy does if you search for newline chars.)

Comment: @Drew exactly, what I need and what I meant, thank you a lot.